# Hive RLIKE on a JOIN synthax

Tags: hadoop, hive, rlike

I have two tables on hive. The first, called 'access', contains apache logs, where the first field is an complete ip adress :

```
10.4.5.12 - - [26/Jun/2010:11:16:09 +1000] "GET /myportal/pageA HTTP/1.1"
10.4.41.2 - - [26/Jun/2010:11:18:09 +1000] "GET /myportal/pageB HTTP/1.1"
10.5.1.111 - - [26/Jun/2010:11:22:09 +1000] "GET /myportal/pageA HTTP/1.1"
192.10.4.177 - - [26/Jun/2010:11:22:41 +1000] "GET /myportal/pageC HTTP/1.1"
```

and an other, called 'client' that contains the beginning of an ip range and a string :

```
10.4 clientA
10.5 clientB
10.7 ClientC
```

I would like to find the total of hits, by client, and display their name. So, I try to join this two tables like this :

> SELECT client.name, count(access.ip) FROM access JOIN client WHERE
>   access.ip RLIKE client.ip GROUP BY client.name;

It works but for the clientA, I get a hit for the last entry (192.10.4.177) of my apache log too, what I don't want. I would like to comparre client.ip only with the beginning of the access.ip.

I suppose a particular regex ... or maybe my synthax is wrong... can someone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RLIKE uses Java regular expressions. So you can use "^" to express starting with something. For example, you can use 'CONCAT("^",client.ip)' to put the "^" before `client.ip`.

```
SELECT client.name, count(access.ip)
FROM access JOIN client
WHERE access.ip RLIKE CONCAT("^",client.ip)
GROUP BY client.name;
```

However, since "." is also a special character in a regular expression that means any character. So the above solution is not perfect. For example, if the client ip is `1.3`, it may match '103.2.3.4'. So a better solution is escaping the "." in the client ip. Here is the final solution:

```
SELECT client.name, count(access.ip)
FROM access JOIN client
WHERE access.ip RLIKE CONCAT("^",REGEXP_REPLACE(client.ip, "\\.", "\\."))
GROUP BY client.name;
```

The first `\\.` means a regular expression `\.` (We need to add "\" to specify "\" in Hive). The second `\\.` means a string `\.`. If you are not familiar with Java regular expression, it may confuse you.

Comment: Yes ! It works fine, thank you. Btw, the use of CONCAT (and RLIKE too) is the same that MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).